# Selenium/Chrome - Launch w/ Profile, save no data

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Initiating driver with selenium without any arguments on the profile will lead you to clean chrome profile: nothing added, copied,synced, logged, installed.

When you load a profile - it starts using it like it's a default profile - it loads whatever it has , have all installed stuff. But it also SAVES data.

Is there a way to launch a profile with Selenium/Chrome but save NOTHING to it, so it will beused like an empty profile - Launched, used, all changes discarded, launch again and have nothing changed?

INCOGNITO Doesn't work as it blocks some features.(e.g several extensions cannot be interacted with when you are in incognito)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible options that I can think of

**Copy the profile**

One is to have a copy of the profile and use that to load the browser

So `/profiles/common_profile` has your profile and when you want to launch chrome your will create a copy of the same to `/profiles/browser_profile`

**Use git in profile**

You can do below in your default profile

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Default profile"
```

After the browser is done you can do a

```
git reset --hard
```